# { a: Array<(s:string) => void>, b: Array<() => void> } // Cannot invoke an expression whose type lacks a call signature

Tags: typescript

Like this question: [Cannot invoke an expression whose type lacks a call signature](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42427393/cannot-invoke-an-expression-whose-type-lacks-a-call-signature) but with functions.

```
    type AFunction = (s:string) => void;
    type BFunction = () => void;
    type Actions = { a: Array<AFunction>, b: Array<BFunction> };
    let actions:Actions = [];

    const doAction = (key:(keyof Actions), foo:(AFunction | BFunction)) => actions[key].push(foo);
```

I get the cannot invoke an expression whose type lacks a call signature. Type ... has no compatible call signature.

I realized through a lot of troubleshooting that the foo is irrelevant. What matters is that actions[key] could be two different kinds of functions and Typescript doesn't know how to call a function that could have two different signatures.

How do i tell Typescript how to call a function that could have two different signatures?

Comment: There's no way to do this which is both easy and type-safe, even if you were to make `doAction()` generic.  (See [a related question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51064527/defining-a-variable-as-one-variant-of-a-discriminated-union-in-typescript) for more info).  You'll probably want to [assert](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/basic-types.html#type-assertions) your way out of this:  `const doAction = (key: (keyof Actions), foo: (AFunction | BFunction)) => (actions[key] as Array<AFunction | BFunction>).push(foo);`

Comment: This did it!

I thought more about what i was trying to achieve and how I would do it in C++ and I see how it'd be impossible do this without making both members a union type. This is simply an impossibility with typing. Still I'm not going to compromise readability for the sake of type safety, so I'll use your solution. Thanks again.